# tkinter: manipulating variables inside tk.Label with textvariable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've just begun learning tkinter, and would like to know if it's possible to manipulate variables in `ttk.Label` on the fly with `textvariable=` or `text=`.  In order to demonstrate, behold my ingenious calculator program which multiplies two numbers and displays the product.:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Multiplier")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

## Calculation

def multiply(*args):
    try:
       product.set(round(float(num1.get())*float(num2.get()),2))
    except ValueError:
        pass

## variables

num1 = StringVar()
num2 = StringVar()
product = DoubleVar()

## first number

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="First Number:").grid(column = 1, row = 1)
num1_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=4, textvariable=num1)
num1_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 1)
num1_entry.bind('<KeyPress>', multiply)
num1_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', multiply)

## second number

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Second Number:").grid(column = 1, row = 2)
num2_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=4, textvariable=num2)
num2_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 2)
num2_entry.bind('<KeyPress>',multiply)
num2_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>',multiply)

## display results

ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Product:").grid(column = 1, row = 3)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=product).grid(column = 2, row = 3)

root.mainloop()
```

I can update the result whenever `product` is changed by using `textvariable=product`.  I can update `product` whenever `num1` or `num2` are changed by binding each to `<KeyPress>` and `<KeyRelease>`.  So far, so good.

What I would like to know is whether it's possible to have another `ttk.Label` which displays my variable, but manipulated in some way.  Let's say I wanted to do something crazy like take my product and multiply it by 2.

I know I could simply create a new variable:

```
newvariable = DoubleVar()
```

then update my `multiply` function thusly:

```
def multiply(*args):
    try:
       product.set(round(float(num1.get())*float(num2.get()),2))
       newvariable.set(round(product.get()*2),2))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

and add my new label:

```
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=newvariable).grid(column=1, row = 5)
```

That solves the problem nicely.  I have a new label that shows me my original product * 2, and is also updated on the fly as my entries are changed.  That's exactly what I want.

In my actual project, however, I need to accomplish this many times over with different arguments.  It seems tedious to add a ton of new variables if I don't need to.

What I'd like to be able to do is something like:

```
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=product*2).grid(column=1, row = 5)
```

That gives me "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'DoubleVar' and 'int'.  I take that to mean that textvariable only wants 1 variable and does not want it manipulated.

I also tried:

```
ttk.Label(mainframe, text=(product.get()*2)).grid(column=1, row = 5)
```

That one doesn't fail, but it also doesn't update automatically.  (That's the whole reason we need `textvariable` in the first place, right?)

Is it even possible to do that without creating a new variable for each different instance where I want to manipulate my original variables?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot associate a function or expression with a label. What you can do, however, is put a trace on your other varianles. The trace will call a function whenever the variable is changed. In that function you can do any calculations you want and then set the value of your label variable.

For more information on traces see http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Variable-class.html#trace, among other places.

Comment: Either way, it would appear that I'm forced to create a new variable to display in the label.  For instance, in my example above, if I have num1 = 2 and num2 = 3, then product = 6.  If I want to simultaneously display `product` in one label and `product * 5` in another label, I cannot do that without creating a new variable to express `product * 5`.

Comment: @Floydius: you are correct, you must create a new variable. You can't associate a widget with an expression, you can only associate a widget with a variable.

Comment: I was hoping I was wrong about that, but at least I can stop trying to google my way around it...  thanks so much for the help!